# Cross-domain does not work with signalr 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a signalr 2.0 server that should serve the multiple domains.. So in need to enable CORS in my server. I user iis7.5 as web server.
I enabled the CORS in `Startup` method of my project as  follows

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
}
}
```

This code is copy and pasted from this article 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

I created a localhost project and try to connect to signalr server.

**But I get the following error in firefox**

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  `http://MyWebSite.com:8082/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sahragostarhub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1405622027746` This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. negotiate

**and this error in chrome**
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://MyWebSite.com:8082/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22sahragostarhub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1405622032883`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '(My Client site address)' is therefore not allowed access

I Also add the following lines to my web.config

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

This change was also useless.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but in angular application using "*" did not work either, we had to specify exact domain.

Comment: All we know is that the headers are not being set correctly. Can you add the headers to your question?

Comment: I suggest using fiddler to inspect the headers your server is actually sending; without that, it's all guesswork

Comment: Have you tried any of suggested answers? Did it help?

Answer (score 6):

Try [removing WebDAV](http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/) module in your configuration (helped me some time ago):

```
<configuration>              
    <system.webServer>                   
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this today, and after poking around a bit, found that the installing the Microsoft.Owin.Cors package resolved the issue for me.

Just run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

Build, and reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

At last my problem is solved after a lot of struggling . It seems that a port number conflict cause this problem .
I stop other web site on my server and stop any other iis express services and then it works fine. Thank you for your attention to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your Application_Start use below code use the overload method of the MapHubs

```
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfiguration.EnableCrossDomain = true;
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(hubConfiguration);
```

Comment: EnableCrossDomain is not in Signal 2.